# node.js response.end() doesn't send message.

Tags: json, node.js, client, response, send

```
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    myfunction(arg1, function(data) {
        res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type":"applicatioin/json"});
        res.end(data);
    });
});
```

If you run the above code,
The data does not go to the client.

Why?

Comment: You have an incorrect `Content-Type` header. If you're sending JSON, why not simply use `res.json()` method?

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if your data is actually json. 'application/json' is the correct content type for json.

It would help me figure out if you could post a bit more of your code.